# CSS + Anchor link to dynamically loaded element from file using jQuery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I need to be able to show only anchored div and to be able to share the link with that anchor. It is not working as expected (try `bar1 (blank)` `bar2 (blank)` link). Loading main.html page (shown below) with an anchor `bar1` or `bar2` (`www.foo.bar/main.html#bar1`) fails to properly handle css and jQuery if `bar1` (or `bar2`) is loaded from file. On the other hand if #foo element is appended as html string then anchored link seems to work (e.g. `www.foo.bar/main.html#foo`). To compare behavior click `foo (blank)`, `bar1 (blank)`, `bar1`, `bar2 (blank)` and `bar2` links, `bar1 (blank)` and `bar2 (blank)` links fail to show `bar1` (or `bar2`) div. Apparently it is related to asynchronous file loading. Is there a way to get around this issue?

**main.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$("<div>").load("bar1.html #bar1", function() {
  $('body').append($(this).html());
});
$("<div>").load("bar2.html #bar2", function() {
  $('body').append($(this).html());
});

$(function() {
    $( 'body' ).append("<div id='foo' style='background-color:#8F8;'>FOO</div>");   
});
        </script>   
        <style>
div:not(:target) { display: none; }
div:target { display: block; }  
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="main.html#foo" target="_blank">foo (blank)</a>
        <a href="main.html#bar1" target="_blank">bar1 (blank)</a>
        <a href="main.html#bar1">bar1</a>
        <a href="main.html#bar2" target="_blank">bar2 (blank)</a>
        <a href="main.html#bar2">bar2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**bar1.html:**

```
<div id='bar1'>BAR1</div>
```

**bar2.html:**

```
<div id='bar2'>BAR2</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a file counter and a function that decrements counter to reset the anchor tag.

**main.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
var count = 2;

function onDataHandled() {
    if (--count <= 0) {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        window.location.hash = '';
        window.location.hash = hash;
    }
}

$.get('bar1.html', function (data) {
    $('body').append(data);
    onDataHandled();
});
$.get('bar2.html', function (data) {
    $('body').append(data);
    onDataHandled();
});

$(function() {
    $( 'body' ).append("<div id='foo' style='background-color:#8F8;'>FOO</div>");  
});
        </script>   
        <style>
div:not(:target) { display: none; }
div:target { display: block; }  
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="main.html#foo" target="_blank">foo (blank)</a>
        <a href="main.html#bar1" target="_blank">bar1 (blank)</a>
        <a href="main.html#bar1">bar1</a>
        <a href="main.html#bar2" target="_blank">bar2 (blank)</a>
        <a href="main.html#bar2">bar2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your fully trying to do.

But try wrapping your jQuery in document ready

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("<div>").load("bar.html #bar", function() {
      $('body').append($(this).html());
    });

    $( 'body' ).append("<div id='foo' style='background-color:#8F8;'>FOO</div>");  

  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't help. I need to be able to show only anchored div and to be able to share the link with that anchor. In this example I expect after pressing "bar (blank)" for opened page to show "BAR", it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for `main.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        div{
            display: none;
        }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("<div>").load("bar.html #bar", function() {
                  $('body').append($(this)[0].innerHTML);
                });
                var hash = window.location.hash;
                $('a').on('click', function(){
                    if(!hash && !($(this).attr('target'))){
                        $('[id="'+$(this).attr('href').substring(1)+'"]').show('slow');
                    }
                });
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('[id="'+hash.substring(1)+'"]').show('slow');
                 }, 100);
                $('body').append("<div id='foo' style='background-color:#8F8;'>FOO</div>");
            });
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#foo" target="_blank">foo (blank)</a>
        <a href="#bar" target="_blank">bar (blank)</a>
        <a href="#bar">bar</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

`bar.html` stays the same

Comment: Updated question to include multiple file loading.
Answer looks too complicated, submitting my own solution.